# "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset -

```
print(df)

  object    group   
1 apple      A    
1 banana     B    
1 pear       A    
1 robot      C

print(df2)

  object    group   
1 apple      A    
1 apple      B    
1 apple      A    
1 robot      C
1 robot      C
1 robot      C
1 banana     C
```

I'd like to count the number of times each value shows up in another data set, which looks exactly the same but draws data from a different time period. The other dataset is called `df2`.

I used this code -

```
x <- df %>%
  mutate(reference = length(df2[df2$object == object,]$object))
```

It gave me this error: `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

It works when I run this outside of dplyr, like this -

```
object <- "apple"
length(df2[df2$object == object,]$object)
```

Can I do a relative reference like that, including `object` in the filter?

Comment: `dplyr` functions work on the whole column taken as a vector. Try `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate...`.

Comment: I used that as the solution. Please refer this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Do I need to do anything, like `ungroup()`, to return it to its normal state after using rowwise()

Comment: @Cauder Ideally, you should do `ungroup` because the output is grouped by row and the grouping would remain if you are going to do some further analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment: dplyr functions work on the whole column taken as a vector. Try

```
df %>%
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(reference = length(df2[df2$object == object,]$object))%>%
ungroup()
```

As you said, `ungroup` will be needed, unless you plan on doing further row-wise operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a `tidyverse` option, we can use `map_dbl`

```
purrr::map_dbl(df$object, ~ length(df2[df2$object == .,]$object))
#[1] 3 1 0 3
```

which can be also calculated with `sum`

```
purrr::map_dbl(df$object, ~ sum(df2$object == .))
```

So in `mutate` we can add

```
df %>%
  mutate(reference = map_dbl(object,  ~ sum(df2$object == .)))

#  object group reference
#1  apple     A         3
#2 banana     B         1
#3   pear     A         0
#4  robot     C         3
```

---

The similar base R option is `sapply`

```
sapply(df$object, function(x) sum(df2$object == x))

# apple banana   pear  robot 
#     3      1      0      3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
reference <- setDT(df2)[df, .N, on = .(object), by = .EACHI]$N
df$reference <- reference
df
#   object group reference
#1:  apple     A         3
#2: banana     B         1
#3:   pear     A         0
#4:  robot     C         3
```